# Is it okay to just give my account number together with another branch's address and SWIFT for foreign fund transfers?

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer

I have a savings account with State Bank of India. However, the branch where I have an account doesn't have a SWIFT code.

I asked my branch and they gave the SWIFT of another branch. I gave the following details to my company: Name, address and SWIFT of the branch with the code and the number of my account. Is that okay for the transfer?

I mean, is there any risk that someone else has the same account number in the other branch and he gets the money instead?

Even if that's not the case, will such a transfer happen with just this information?

Comment: SBI is moving to Core Banking. So if your account number is 17-19 Digits long, there is nothing to worry as its unique across all Branches.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [swift codes](http://www.theswiftcodes.com/) website, but on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362), there seems to be some variation in the interpretation of the standard.

Broadly, it should be that a swift code refers to a particular branch, but it is possible that there is a cost associated with running a swift code, so some banks may prefer to share swift codes across branches. You should check and confirm.